# Disabling caps lock by setxkbmap makes it Shift key in Emacs

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, keyboard, emacs, xfce

I'm using GNU Emacs 23.2.1. within Xfce 4.8.0 (both coming from the Ubuntu Natty repository).  I disable the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> by running `/usr/bin/setxkbmap -option "ctrl:nocaps"` at the beginning of the Xfce session.

When I hit the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key with some other keys, Emacs treats it as if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key is pressed (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>-whatever).  This has some unpleasant effects such as moving cursors always setting marks, and translating <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>h</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>?</kbd> not working.

Pressing the real <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key on the keyboard works fine, and pressing both the real <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> key works the same way as pressing the real <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key only.

I'd like the <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to be precisely same as the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key.  What should I do?  I tweaked the X server setting in vain, so I think I might want to make Emacs treat <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd>-whatever as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use xmodmap and it work fine. Install xmodmap and have `xmodmap .xmod` autostart.
Content of .xmod.

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
keycode 66 = Control_L NoSymbol Control_L
add Control = Control_L
```

Maybe your keycode is different.

Comment: The problem with xmodmap was that it caused X server error with some combination of commands.  But your example worked.  Thanks.  Could you tell me why you assign NoSymbol as a second keysym for keycode 66?

Comment: You can try `xmodmap -pke | grep Control`